# unable to update the Google Cloud SQL TimeZone without re-creating the instances

Tags: sql-server, google-cloud-platform, timezone

We have run into a production issue where clients are complaining about the TimeZone on the MS SQL Server Instances.

Based on my cursory look in the console I am unable to update the Google Cloud SQL TimeZone without re-creating the instances. Is there a process to get around this?

It would be quite a bit of work for me to backup, recreate, and restore each of the instances.

backup, recreate, and restore each of the instances.
But dont want to keep doing this as its too much work